# Puppet cert clean not working

Tags: linux, puppet, certificate

So, I am standing up a new server to replace an existing one.  Should be easy, right?  Revoke the old cert, create a new one and off you go.  Here's the loop I am stuck in:

I've redacted the server names, cert fingerprint and domain.  The servers shown below are:

- Slave1 -- The machine that will be the *partner of* the one that is having issues.  It is only mentioned below to prove one of the details.
- Slave2 -- The machine that is giving me issues.
- Master1 -- The puppet master (obviously)

On new build

```
[root@slave2 ~]# puppet agent -t
Error: Could not request certificate: The certificate retrieved from the master does not match the agent's private key.
Certificate fingerprint: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:2F:F1
To fix this, remove the certificate from both the master and the agent and then start a puppet run, which will automatically regenerate a certficate.
On the master:
puppet cert clean slave2.example.com
On the agent:
  rm -f /var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/slave2.example.com.pem
  puppet agent -t

Exiting; failed to retrieve certificate and waitforcert is disabled
```

Okay, that's predictable and fully expected because this is a new server using an old name.  Now on the master:

```
[root@master1 ~]# puppet cert clean slave2.example.com
Notice: Revoked certificate with serial 154
```

Note that there's nothing about the key files getting removed.  This is because they are not there.  Proof:

```
[root@master1 ~]# ls /var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca/signed/slave1.example.com.pem
/var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca/signed/slave1.example.com.pem
[root@master1 ~]# ls /var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca/signed/slave2.example.com.pem
ls: cannot access /var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca/signed/slave2.example.com.pem: No such file or directory
```

Okay, good.  Now go back to the slave to complete the procedure by removing the .pem file and running puppet agent again:

```
[root@slave2 ~]# rm -f /var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/slave2.example.com.pem
[root@slave2 ~]# puppet agent -t
Info: Caching certificate for slave2.example.com
Error: Could not request certificate: The certificate retrieved from the master does not match the agent's private key.
Certificate fingerprint: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:2F:F1
To fix this, remove the certificate from both the master and the agent and then start a puppet run, which will automatically regenerate a certficate.
On the master:
  puppet cert clean slave2.example.com
On the agent:
  rm -f /var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/slave2.example.com.pem
  puppet agent -t

Exiting; failed to retrieve certificate and waitforcert is disabled
```

...and we are right back where we started with no change in outcome.

One last sanity check:

```
[root@master1 ~]# puppet cert list -a | grep -i slave2
```

...and there are no matches.

What am I doing wrong?

**Addendum:**

I'm inclined to believe that it is on the master, but not sure exactly how.  Here's why:

```
[root@master1 ~]# puppet cert clean slave2.example.com
Notice: Revoked certificate with serial 154
[root@master1 ~]# puppet cert clean slave2.example.com
Notice: Revoked certificate with serial 154
[root@master1 ~]# puppet cert clean slave2.example.com
Notice: Revoked certificate with serial 154
[root@master1 ~]# puppet cert clean slave2.example.com
Notice: Revoked certificate with serial 154
[root@master1 ~]# puppet cert clean slave2.example.com
Notice: Revoked certificate with serial 154
```

Shouldn't that fail after the first time, because of the cert no longer being there?

Comment: try find /var/lib/puppet/ssl/ -type f -name '\*slave2\*' on master and on slave too

Comment: @c4f4t0r Thanks for the suggestion.  There were no results on master1.  On slave2, I found the certs, but I have already (at someone else's suggestion) tried deleting that whole file tree (/var/lib/puppet/ssl) on slave2 to make it start over.  It did not get me anwhere.

Answer (score 1):

A Redditor provided a detailed step-by-step that seems to have resolved the issue.  The three key things were:

- Make sure that the clocks are in sync (they were)
- Make sure that the puppet service is stopped (it wasn't)
- Invoke puppet agent with an explicitly defined target for the master, e.g.

> ```
> puppet agent -t --server master1.example.com
> ```

That combination of things got us past the cert issue.

Answer (score 0):

`puppet ca` is being deprecated though and may not work, but please try:

`puppet ca destroy slave2.example.com`

Also check the `/var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca/requests` directory for any pending request certificates manually even though `puppet cert list -a` isn't showing anything. Infact, do a `ls -lRa /var/lib/puppet/ssl/` on the master and search for the slave2 cert, just to be sure.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion.  I did try this already yesterday, however, I ran it again just now to confirm.  The response was "Nothing was deleted".

Comment: More things to try:

# On Client: (Get the proper certname from client just to be sure using below cmd: )

`puppet config print certname`


# On master:
`puppet node deactivate <certname>`

`puppet node purge <certname>`


---
Also make sure the certname is set in puppet config as 


`certname = slave2.example.com`


and then try running puppet: `puppet agent -tv`

-- just some basics that is easy to miss out while cloning machines. :)

Comment: thank you for the suggestion.  puppet config print certname does return the expected value.  puppet node deactivate and puppet node purge are not valid on this version of Puppet (3.8.7).  I did try puppet node clean slave2.example.com but it doesn't seem to have done anything useful.  It leaves us still where we were.